Repeated short identical parallel jobs
I have an algorithm that requires many parallel reruns of the same code. The code is short and finishes in less than a microsecond. This will be run millions of times which creates some problems when using threads. I'm trying to make use of POSIX threads, but since the overhead of creating new threads is not an option, I need to use some kind of spinning worker thread that is constantly running instead.
Below is a simplified case and illustrates how I'm trying to run two equally long works, calc_x and calc_y. I need to be able to run them in parallel so that the total time taken is like running just one (or very close).
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int nloops = 100;
static int x;
static int y;
static pthread_t tid;
static atomic_bool trun;
static atomic_bool texit;
static int cnt = 0;
static const int MILLION = 1000000;


void calc_x() {
    x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nloops; ++i) {
        x += i;
    }
}

void calc_y() {
    y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nloops; ++i) {
        y += i;
    }
}

void *worker() {
    while (1) {
        if (trun) {
            calc_x();
            trun = false;
        }
        if (texit) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

float run_x() {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < MILLION; ++i) {
        calc_x();
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    return (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)*0.000000001;
}

float run_y() {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < MILLION; ++i) {
        calc_y();
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    return (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)*0.000000001;
}

float run_xy() {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < MILLION; ++i) {
        calc_x();
        calc_y();
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    return (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)*0.000000001;
}

float run_xy_parallel() {
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < MILLION; ++i) {
        trun = true;
        calc_y();
        while(trun) ++cnt;
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    return (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)*0.000000001;
}

int main() {
    trun = false;
    texit = false;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &worker, NULL);
    printf("run_x: %.4f s\n", run_x());
    printf("run_y: %.4f s\n", run_y());
    printf("run_xy: %.4f s\n", run_xy());
    printf("run_xy_parallel: %.4f s\n", run_xy_parallel());
    printf("average nr of waiting loops: %.1f\n", (float)cnt/MILLION);
    texit = true;
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}

The results are:
run_x: 0.3049 s
run_y: 0.2559 s
run_xy: 0.5074 s
run_xy_parallel: 0.4744 s
average nr of waiting loops: 34.9

As you can see, there is practically no gain from using the parallel worker. The count (cnt) I'm using to try to measure how long time is spent on waiting suggests that 35/nloops = 35% of the time of calc_x is spend waiting for the other thread to finish, which seems right since there is a time difference between run_x and run_y.
So I changed nloops to 1000 to see if anything changed. I got these results:
run_x: 2.4921 s
run_y: 2.4965 s
run_xy: 5.0950 s
run_xy_parallel: 3.3477 s
average nr of waiting loops: 44.8

Now the waiting count is less than 5% of calc_x. But still it's 1/3 slower than than what I expect.
It seems to me that setting trun takes alot of time, but it doesn't make sense that that time increases with nloops.
Can anyone please explain this to me?

False sharing ? Add a 100 bytes of padding between them and re-run.

Also have you tried using openmp ? It uses a threadpool which limits the number of times threads are created.

Thanks for helping. I read about it and it seems to make sense since the overhead increases with nloops. So I added padding of different sizes between x and y, but unfortunately with no effect. I haven't tried openmp yet.. I think I need an answer to this before I can move on to other alternatives.

Since your threads share data, scheduling them on different CPUs would likely reduce performance.

@stark, how so? I don't understand why

I'm sorry @CarlHR, but I don't follow your logic. To be honest, I don't think you understand the code. In run_xy_parallel calc_x is called once the worker loop reaches trun which has been changed to true. There is nothing that guarantees that calc_x start before calc_y or the other way around.

@CarlHR, no that is not what is happening. I know what I'm doing here, my logic is fine, that is not the problem I have. The problem is what happens behind the hood. As AhmedAEK mentioned, it might have something to do with false sharing. I still don't know. But I'm very sure calc_x and calc_y at least overlap.

I'm not sure why your threads are spinning while waiting for the other thread to finish. Why can't you let the threads quit when they are finished doing their work or use something like a semaphore to wait on?


You should really enable optimizations for anything related to profiling and benchmarking. Here, the timings tends to indicate optimizations are disabled. If you enable -O2 or -O3, both Clang and GCC optimize out your loops (so the benchmark is biased). 2. Alignment indeed help though it is not enough alone to make the parallel version significantly faster on my machine. 3. inter-core communication has a significant latency for several reasons. 4. global variables are generally bad (especially non-constant one). They tend to increase race conditions, false/true sharing issues.



You should check frequency scaling is not an issue nor thread migration. Servers often have a higher inter-core latency so 1 µs is a pretty tight limit on such machine. 6. some includes are apparently missing in your C code (eg. stdbool.h and time.h not to mention some function seems to be non-standard and require a GNU/POSIX define).



Hammering an atomic variable can be detrimental for performance. More generally spin-locks tends to be faster in some cases but also much more dangerous and sometimes slower than locks, but for a 1 µs limit, they seems suited as long as they are use with extreme caution (a context switch is generally more expensive). Maybe you should use a real-time OS too.



Be aware that 1 µs is generally considered too small for multi-threading to be useful on multiple cores (though it is actually dependent on the target machine). Maybe you should put the 2 threads on the same core and benefit from SMT. It should significantly reduce the latency of atomics (and more generally data sharing). However, each thread will be slower than on 2 cores. Note that spin lock hammering will certainly strongly decrease performance in this case so you should fix that first.


Not sure why your question is getting downvoted that much. I've had to do this kind of performance analysis and it's both tricky and necessary for certain kinds of applications (e.g. financial services).
My best guess pinning threads to cores. Most decent-size servers have multiple CPU sockets, so you should taskset your process to ensure that it will run on cores restricted to a single NUMA zone. Even if your server only has a single CPU socket, Linux likes to migrate threads across cores, which prevents optimal cache usage. Ideally, you would explicitly pin the threads to cores chosen to be as close as possible, cache-wise. I have found that even on a single CPU system, the choice of cores to pin to has a significant impact on performance. Try different ones till you find a pair that gives you the best performance.
I think "false sharing" was a good guess. X86 processors all have 64-byte cachlines, so you should definitely add a char array of (64-sizeof(int)) between each of the globals (or at least the "hot" ones). In fact, I'm not sure C guarantees globals to be packed in a predictable way, so you might want to put them in a struct.
And your idea of increasing nloops was a good one. Synchronizing the threads after only 100 loops isn't enough.
A lot of my work has been related to network performance using kernel bypass drivers like Onload. Hardware configuration plays into it, trying to make sure that all memory accesses, including the NIC, are local. Interrupts also play a role, stealing cycles from the CPU you're trying to monopolize. There are any number of hacks you can do to isolate cores from the Linux scheduler and interrupt processing, although this can be quite a rabbit hole. Here are some links from several years ago when I did a bunch of research:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt
https://jeremyeder.com/2013/11/15/nohz_fullgodmode/
https://www.codethink.co.uk/articles/2018/configuring-linux-to-stabilise-latency/
https://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html
https://engineering.linkedin.com/performance/optimizing-linux-memory-management-low-latency-high-throughput-databases

Here's another wonderful resource for seeing the consequences of various coding approaches: https://godbolt.org/

Thanks. As I'm reading more about it, I understand how memory locality plays a big role here. Your explanation led me to find the answers I need. I have now tried to pin to different cores and the results are varying drastically. There are obviously many things to consider if one will make this work. Maybe it's possible to build or configure a computer specifically for this case. I will have to think about this..

I just added a list-o-links to the end of the answer for your late-night reading pleasure.

Many thanks! I am reading into it. Very interesting to see how much is actually possible to control. I'll try to tune a bit while also realizing the limitations.

I have done some investigation. I tried changing MILLION - it didn't help.
Then I read about false sharing, and tried to work with local copies of x and y.
new code of calc_x, calc_y :

void calc_x() {
    int xloc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nloops; ++i) {
        xloc += i;
    }
    x = xloc;
}

void calc_y() {
    y = 0;
    int yloc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nloops; ++i) {
        yloc += i;
    }
    y = yloc;
}

And problem completely disappeared!
Here are times:
# non local version (MILLION is 10000 nloops = 100000)

run_x: 6.1838 s
run_y: 6.1812 s
run_xy: 12.3375 s
run_xy_parallel: 7.8648 s
average nr of waiting loops: 2741.4

# static version with x and y divided by buf[100]

static int x;
static int buf[100];
static int y;

... Result times: ...

run_x: 1.8734 s
run_y: 1.8513 s
run_xy: 3.7081 s
run_xy_parallel: 1.8359 s
average nr of waiting loops: 143.8


# MILLION is 10000 nloops = 100000

run_x: 1.7826 s
run_y: 1.7460 s
run_xy: 3.5052 s
run_xy_parallel: 1.7342 s
average nr of waiting loops: 242.5

# MILLION is 100000 nloops = 10000

run_x: 1.7939 s
run_y: 1.7632 s
run_xy: 3.5415 s
run_xy_parallel: 1.7667 s
average nr of waiting loops: 52.2



program sped up about 5 times (may be local variable can be easily moved to register???), and parallel version runs exactly 2 times faster, as it should.
Almost the same speed up and parallel efficiency was achieved by putting 400 bytes buffer between x and y, so they can be cached independently.
May be in your version static x and y near each other really prevented caching, as some people here wrote.
And generally to gain with parallel computations you should hold programs as independent as possible.

The thing I like about this answer is the suggestion to make the "work" of the calculation happen with locals, which as mishagam demonstrates, speeds it up dramatically. Among other things, it lets the optimizer do its job. Then at the end of the local work, just pass back the results. This is a model that is used a lot with parallel processing.
FYI to @mishagam, using static globals does not prevent caching, but does prevent the optimizer from producing efficient code.

This sounds great. I tested myself but couldn't get the same results, no matter what value on nloops. Also the results vary between different runs. I think there are many things going on, although I believe this can be a part of the solution.

Answer to @SreveFord I tried version with static x and y separated by 400 bytes buffer - and it produced almost the same speed up, I put times in answer - so main problem apparently was broken caching.

@mishagam - Interesting. I'll try to reproduce your results and play around with it. If I find anything exciting, I'll post here and ping you.
